# Datatype for Float in SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

[image]

I have issues with Float data type in SSIS Package.

I used the data type Float [DT_R8].

Below are the screen shots.

Here is the sample table.

```
Customer  
1020.29   
101.2934  
2092.125  
2.092126  
921.27    

In SQL :

Customer
102029
1012934
2092125
2092126
92127
```

What I'm I missing here. I read the other posts and used [DT_R8] for float.

I have also written it to a flatfile and it is the same.

![Screenshots from the SSIS File connection][2]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't u just use the data conversion task to help assist you with making sure the end result is the float.  I have a feeling the initial metadata is what is causing you trouble.